# Install dotnet 4.7.2 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: asp.net, linux, ubuntu

I would like to install dotnet runtime version 4.7.2 on ubuntu 20.04. I tried running the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-4.7.2
```

However, I get an error saying the package cannot be found. I am not sure if 4.7.2 is supported in ubuntu 20.04.

Can anybody help me with this issue ?
Thank You

Comment: .NET Framework is only supported on Windows, .NET Core is supported on multiple operating systems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the asp.net is for windows Operating systems only. Check [ASP.NET Framework system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements).

You may try the [.Net Core 3.0 (system requirements)](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md) that have Support for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Check out Mono which can be run on Linux https://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Interesting Project